# docker-compose: spring-boot web service access postgres db service

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker-compose

In my docker-compose.yal file I define a spring-boot based web service and a postgresql database service. The web services references the db services and has an environment variable for the database datasource URL where it needs to reference the hostname of the database service. This is what it looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    container_name: medmap-server
    hostname: medmap-server
    build: ../../../build/docker
    ports: ["8090:8090"]
    links:
      - db:database
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://medmap-db:5433/medmapdb
      - spring.datasource.username=docker
      - spring.datasource.password=docker      
      - logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

  db:
    container_name: medmap-db
    hostname: medmap-db
    image: postgres:9.6.2
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/medmap/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=medmapdb
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/medmap/data/pgdata
```

When I start this application using `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

```
medmap-server | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to medmap-db:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections
.
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:239) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:127) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:41) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:414) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar!/:na]
medmap-server |         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:
5.0.12.Final]
medmap-server |         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5
.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
medmap-server |         at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.ExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ExtractionContextImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
medmap-server |         ... 38 common frames omitted
medmap-server | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
medmap-server |         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
medmap-server |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
medmap-server |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
medmap-server |         at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
medmap-server |         at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
medmap-server |         at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:121) ~[postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar!/:9.4]
medmap-server |         ... 58 common frames omitted
medmap-server |
medmap-server exited with code 1
```

What I do not know is how the pg_hba.conf file is created to allow the web service in one container to access the db service in another container. TIA for any help on this.

Comment: what's in postgres logs? are you sure about port? default is 5432, not 5433

Comment: Good suggestion. Postgresql was running on 5432. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default port for postgres is 5432](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html), try defining it instead of 5433

> port (integer) The TCP port the server listens on; 5432 by default.
>   Note that the same port number is used for all IP addresses the server
>   listens on. This parameter can only be set at server start.

Answer (score 0):

My thanks to @vao-tsun for suggesting I look at the postgres port.

I looked at port used by postgres in my db service by staring a bash shell on the db service's conatiner using:

`docker exec -i -t medmap-db /bin/bash`

And then in the bash shell executing following psql command:

`psql -U postgres -c "SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'port';"`

This showed that I was using port 5432 rather than 5423 which is what my web service was using in its IDBC URL specified by spring.datasource.url env variable.

To fix this I needed to specify PGPORT=5433 env variable in my db service. A common mistake is to assume that the ports field in docker-compose tells what port the service should use. The port fields just declares ports used by service. You need to configure ports for your service in service-specific manner (for postgres it was the env variable PGPORT).

Below is my revised docker-compose.yml file that worked:

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    container_name: medmap-server
    hostname: medmap-server
    build: ../../../build/docker
    ports: ["8090:8090"]
    links:
      - db:database
    environment:
      - server.port=8090
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://medmap-db:5433/medmapdb
      - spring.datasource.username=postgres
      - spring.datasource.password=postgres      
#      - logging.level.org.hibernate=DEBUG

  db:
    container_name: medmap-db
    hostname: medmap-db
    image: postgres:9.6.2
    ports:
      - "5433:5433"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/medmap/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=medmapdb
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/medmap/data/pgdata
      - PGPORT=5433
```